# Simple PHP XML Parser

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm a newbie to PHP so require some help if possible, it's probably a really simple answer but i'm struggling with it.

I'm trying to get some data from a William Hill XML feed.

I'd like to pull out:

- Competition
- Teams Playing
- Kick Off Time
- Team 1 + odds
- Draw + odds
- Team 2 + odds

Here is a link to the XML feed - http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=MR&filterBIR=N

So far I have the code below which isn't pulling out all the data i need and it's only bring back one fixture.

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=MR&filterBIR=N');


$data = $xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market;
$ps = $data->participant;
foreach($ps as $p)
{
echo $p['name']." - ".$p['odds']."<br />";
}

?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

```
    <?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=1&marketSort=MR&filterBIR=N');


$data = $xml->response->williamhill->class->type;

foreach($data as $type) {
    foreach($type->market as $market) {
        if(strpos($market['name'], "Match Betting")) {
            echo $market['name'] . "<br/>";
            $competition = $type['name'];
            $kickoff = $market['time'];
            $date = $market['date'];
            $ps = $market->participant;

            echo "Competition: " . $competition . "<br/>";
            echo "Kickoff: " . $kickoff . "<br/>";
            echo "Date: " . $date . "<br/>";

    foreach($ps as $p) {
        echo $p['name']." - ".$p['odds']."<br />";
    }

    echo "<br><br/>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

The reason it was only getting one entry was because you were not looping through each market it would only pick the first market and loop through the first set. You will need to add an additional loop to get every entry printed to the screen because there is more than one `type` listed

Comment: Yeah that's looping now, any idea how i'd pull out the competition ie. Premier Leauge, fixture ie. manchester united vs arsenal and kick off time, and also seperate the list? Sorry - really know very little php

Comment: You need to add another loop and loop over each "Type" and extract "Name" from it. I will update my answer shortly with the correct way.

Comment: @MikeDean check the updated answer. Please accept if you feel it answered your initial problem.

Comment: almost there... i've slightly changed it myself that seems to work a bit better for my needs.. see edited above.

Comment: @MikeDean updated. it needed to have a statement to check the name field of each market for the string "Match Betting"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! This is just the beginning but it gives me so much to work with now.

Answer (score 0):

Simplexml objects are not arrays, which can be confusing at first. Convert the object to an array and it is much easier to handle:

`var_dump((array) $xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market));`

this can be done at any point in the structure. Note that attributes are stored under the `@attributes` key.